# Is it okay to not varnish wooden furniture before use?

Tags: wood, wooden-furniture, bedroom, varnishing

I recently bought a bedframe, but due to budget constraints, I didn't choose the varnished option, just 'unstained raw timber' - which is smooth, but not varnished or stained, as described.

I'm just wondering if this will be alright, unvarnished, for general use? I assumed because it's not flooring or visible furniture, that having an unvarnished bedframe will be alright.

There won't be any worries about it coming in contact with water spillage, etc. And will be mostly away from light sources.

Comment: Unless you live in a crazy humid location, the varnish would not do much of practical value in your circumstance.

Comment: Unless you seal the wood skin oils (human and pet) will stain the wood.

Comment: The unstained unvarnished option is probably provided for those who want a particular stain or paint color....

Answer (score 2):

Not finishing wood is perfectly fine.

It will be more prone to collecting dirt and stains than finished wood, but if you don't mind that, it's still fine.

If your budget allows, you can also apply finish yourself, some of which are quite inexpensive and relatively easy. But you don't have to.

If at some later point you feel that the dirt and stains acquired are annoying, you can sand the wood to remove them, and apply finish then if you want to; or simply repeat as needed.

Comment: I agree, except that any oily substance (including skin oils) are difficult to remove. Surely you have access to some low-cost sealer. Big box stores have clearances and "oops" deals all the time. We're talking a few dollars and an hour of your time.